# Accessing the proc_dir_entry from proc_fops.open?

Tags: linux, kernel, procfs

I writing a linux kernel module that does some work with /proc... I'm trying to use the new seq methods for returning the data for /proc... Anyhow, after I call proc_create_data() I have a proc_dir_entry (whose ->data member is pointing at my supplied context)... Anyhow, the file_operations structure is also passed and I really need to know how to access either the proc_dir_entry or the proc_dir_entry->data from the open() file operation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the PDE macro to convert the inode* into a pointer to the proc_dir_entry, which of course had a "data" member pointing at what I needed.

```
struct proc_dir_entry* pde = PDE( inode );
```